# .NET Jump List

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

Is there a .NET library/tutorial available that will let me show me how to customize the Windows 7 Jump List for my application?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

channel9.msdn.com did a series of discussions covering the new taskbar, including the jumplist.

[Jump Into Windows 7 Taskbar Jump Lists](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/yochay/Jump-into-the-Windows-7-Taskbar-Jump-Lists/)

Additionally, The Windows 7 Blog started a series of posts that covering developing the task-bar, including how to work with jump-lists. You can view their initial post at http://blogs.msdn.com/yochay/archive/2009/01/06/windows-7-taskbar-part-1-the-basics.aspx

Comment: Just FYI, full task bar support, including jump lists, progress bar, and thumbnail customization, was added in .NET 4.0 under the [System.Windows.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 6):

Windows 7 API Code Pack contains the official implementation for .NET, see http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Answer (score 5):

Also it looks like this question has already been answered:
[Another Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437212/how-do-you-register-a-most-recently-used-list-with-windows-in-preparation-for-win)

And here is the simplest way to fill your jump list with the contents of your app's recent files list ([Thanks Code Project!](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell2.aspx):

```
    void AddFileToRecentFilesList(string fileName)
    {
        SHAddToRecentDocs((uint)ShellAddRecentDocs.SHARD_PATHW, fileName);          
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Native call to add the file to windows' recent file list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uFlags">Always use (uint)ShellAddRecentDocs.SHARD_PATHW</param>
    /// <param name="pv">path to file</param>
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern void SHAddToRecentDocs(UInt32 uFlags,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String pv);

    enum ShellAddRecentDocs
    {
        SHARD_PIDL = 0x00000001,
        SHARD_PATHA = 0x00000002,
        SHARD_PATHW = 0x00000003
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

See here [Windows Team Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/05/18/windows-7-managed-code-apis.aspx). Microsoft are working on .Net wrappers for a lot of the new Windows 7 features.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from .NET 4.0 JumpLists can be used easily with [System.Windows.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.aspx) namespace.

See reference and code examples at Microsoft's official [JumpList Class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.jumplist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).