# Taking advantage of Windows 7 RC using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-7, jump-list

I want to take advantage of the new features in Windows 7 using C# (ie. JumpList, Window Shake, etc). Are there any websites/tutorials that can show me what I want to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this link. Good info:

http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/05/18/windows-7-managed-code-apis.aspx

Comment: funny, I just saw that blog today - looks interesting.

Comment: Yea, I haven't had a chance to mess with it yet, but I really want to mess with the Jump Lists. I can see that being really powerful, and helpful to your end user.

Answer (score 1):

[.NET Jump List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466726/net-jump-list)

http://www.vcskicks.com/aero-shake.php

Answer (score 1):

The library is available at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Answer (score 0):

I found a link on how to perform the JumpList using the WindowsAPICodePack from MSDN.

[Click Here to watch video](http://video.msn.com/video.aspx?mkt=en-us&vid=e93f69cc-1f30-4c19-b9ae-83ee8354eaf1)