# Problem showing thumbnail toolbar in .net 3.5 form

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-7, jump-list, thumbnail-toolbar

I am usign WindowsApiCodePack for windows 7 to make a thumbnail toolbar for my form. In the form shown event i am doing this:

```
tbButton1 = new ThumbnailToolbarButton(new Icon("myOverlayIcn.ico"), "Next Event");    
tbButton1.Click += new EventHandler<ThumbnailButtonClickedEventArgs>(button1_Click);    
tbButton2 = new ThumbnailToolbarButton(new Icon("myOverlayIcn.ico"), "Next Event");    
tbButton2.Click += new EventHandler<ThumbnailButtonClickedEventArgs>(button2_Click);    
TaskbarManager.Instance.ThumbnailToolbars.AddButtons(this.Handle, tbButton1, tbButton2);
```

I am getting the following error of which i have no idea:

> Error  1   The type 'System.Windows.UIElement' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

I am following using this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EventInTime.aspx

Comment: the error is on:
TaskbarManager.Instance.ThumbnailToolbars.AddButtons(this.Handle, tbButton1, tbButton2);

Comment: i think the problem should in the icons i am giving to buttons

Comment: i am able to display the overlay icon by doing this,
 TaskbarManager.Instance.SetOverlayIcon(new Icon("myOverlayIcn.ico"), "Some Status");

but its giving the above error for thunmbnailtoolbar button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message states, you need to add a reference to PresentationCore.  It's required by the Windows API CodePack, but not referenced in your application.

Comment: thanks, this link will help
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/e1a26812-def5-4dc5-b667-88e8b205df56