# Properties.Resources the icon name does not appear in the intellisense

Tags: c#, windows-7, resources, icons, thumbnails

I am trying to make a thumbnail toolbar for which I need an icon. So I added the icon using the solution explorer in the resources folder. Now, when I do `Properties.Resources` the icon name does not appear. 
Code can be found here:

[Problem showing thumbnail toolbar in .net 3.5 form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519181/problem-showing-thumbnail-toolbar-in-net-3-5-form)

Comment: Properties.Resources the icon name does not appear in the intellisense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to add the icon to the Resources.resx file. Open it in Visual Studio and drag your icon into the Icons menu of the resx and it will become available.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @fletcher you need to add the icon to `Resources.resx` file.

- You find the `Resources.resx` file in the **Solution Explorer** -> **YourProject** -> **Properties**. Right-click and open either **Properties** or `Resourses.resx`
- Right-click **YourProject** in the **Solution Explorer** and open **Properties**. You'll find a Resource-Tab on the project-page.

*Note:* Add your icon as `Icon` in the resource-editor.

Further info on [Adding and Editing Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project/ Properties/ Click on "Resources" mostly after Debug button.

Click on ComboBox, select Images (default its String).

Click on Add Resources. Click on "Add Existing File". Select the image you want to add.

once the image get added to the Resources folder, you can use it.

Ex: btn1.Image = Properties.Resources.Stop; //(Stop - image name)

Answer (score 0):

In my case even images were available in *Resources.rsx* files, i can not access it via `global::Form1.Properties.Resources.books`. So i go to `Resources.rsx` files by double clicking, and on the top there was **Access Modifier** option, i chose **Public** and then it magically works :)

Hope this helps anyone else too.