# Properties.Resources not loading an image

Tags: c#, resources

I have a game application in Visual Studio 2012 C#. I have all the .png images I am using in the Resources file of the project.

Have you any idea why I can access all the files but one by using Properties.Resources?

I checked the full filePath and it's set to the resources folder. And it's added in the program as I did Add -> Existing Item and added the image.

It looks just like the other images. I have no idea why it's not loading. I need this since I need to send a .exe by email to my lecturer and without this image the project is nothing!

[image]

I added this in the resource file

```
internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap grid_fw {
            get
            {
                object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("grid.fw", resourceCulture);
                return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
            }
        }
```

and although now grid is available, it is returning null :/

Comment: yes you can :P using tranZit.. the email works fine but the grid doesn't load :/

Comment: well, how did you add that image to the project? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28VS.80%29.aspx on how to add them

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found from: [Properties.Resources the icon name does not appear in the intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520173/properties-resources-the-icon-name-does-not-appear-in-the-intellisense)

> You also need to add the icon to the `Resources.resx` file. Open it in
>   Visual Studio and drag your icon into the Icons menu of the resx and
>   it will become available.

Also, see [Adding and Editing Resources (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Ohh ok I didn't drag it in the Resources.resx file but added it in the coding only! Solved the problem! Thanks a lot :)))

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the image the following way:

```
Image myImage = Resources.yourImage;
```

If you want to make a *copy* of the image, you'll need to do the following:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Resources.yourImage);
```

Don't forget to dispose of *bmp* when you're done with it.  If you don't know the name of the resource image at compile-time, you can use a resource manager:

```
ResourceManager rm = Resources.ResourceManager;
Bitmap yourImage = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject("yourImage");
```

The benefit of the ResourceManager is that you can use it where Resources.myImage would normally be out of scope, or where you want to dynamically access resources.  Additionally, this works for sounds, config files, etc.

Comment: Thanks I was trying to get image using ResourceManager, but it did return null, but when I used Resources.myImage it did what expected. What could be the cause for ResourceManager returning null?