# Having Trouble Accessing an Embedded Resource

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, resources

When I try to call:

```
Properties.Resources.needle
```

I get the error:

```
error CS0117: 'MinesweeperSolver.Properties.Resources' does not contain a definition for 'needle'
```

I added needle.bmp as a resource. I am using VS2012.

I've already tried changing the access modifier to public.

Edit: Doing `Resources.needle` instead of `Properties.Resources.needle` seemed to have worked.

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/13808403/3123860 after a lot of searching.

Comment: If you solved your problem go ahead and post your solution as an answer to your question to complete the loop and help any one else that may have the same problem in the future.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia: I tried but it doesn't let me because I'm a new user.