# How to add "Last used documents" to a WPF programms tray symbol (not icon) programatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, trayicon, jump-list

I want to provide a list of "last used documents" to the bigger tray icon (not notification icons) of my application.

As shortcut to the user, similar to like *Keypass* or *Microsoft Word* do it when right clicking on it's tray icon if the application is started.

I do not want to put them into the tray icon context menu.

[image: Example of shortcuts to documents - by KeyPass2]

I am unsure if that is a feature that Word provides or if its somehow linked to "what files should be opened by which application" of Windows itself.

I have searched SO / google with keywords like `"tray icon"`,  `"last used documents"` - but the hits more or less discuss

- how to change the icon of a program
- how to addthe smaller icons to the far right of the screen
- how to create apps w/o them popping up in the tray bar at all
- how to create context menues on tray icons

I got all of that already.

I was unable to find questions related to the popup in the above picture that is there when the program is running.

Any ideas?

---

Q&A from comments:

- Feature is called [jump-list](/questions/tagged/jump-list) / Tasks , thanks to @PanagiotisKanavos
- Screenshot is Windows 10, I need it back for Win 8 if appliccable. I can sort the Win 8/8.1 stuff out myself if I get some hints what to look for in Win 10.

Comment: I am able to answer/ provide more details in comments in for about 30 minutes. After it I am offline for ~16 hours - sorry for that.

Comment: What is the correct name of this feature? Starting from which version of windows? Without knowing what is it you can't find it (term "bigger tray icon" imply you don't). Is it called ["recent files"](https://www.howtogeek.com/274573/how-do-you-get-the-all-recent-files-list-back-in-windows-10/)? I mean is it showing the list of "recent files"?

Comment: @Sinatr  it is windows 10 - if I knew how it is called I could search for it better then I did - sorry, don't know. Rightclick f.e. Explorer-Icon and you see stmh like "often used" ("Häufig benutz"t in German) that is autopopulated with files you navigate to often.

Comment: @PatrickArtner it's called a [Jump List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.jumplist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), available since Windows 7. Check [Adding Support for Windows 7 Jump Lists & Taskbar Tabs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg281362.aspx)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks :) want to answer it?

Comment: Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.jumplist?view=netframework-4.7.1) for more information about the JumpList and how to configure them with XAML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Jump List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466726/net-jump-list)